# How to use vs code emmet javascript variable, variable name and method in one statement

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, emmet

In javascript writing every time

`document.querySelector`

looks too much time. 
Is there any way to short writing using vscode emmet. 
For example, I need to write

`const demo = document.querySelector('.demo')`

can I write like this

`const{demo}=dq(.demo) // it'w wrong need right ans` than Tab or enter.

than it will change

`const demo = document.querySelector('.demo')`

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function (just once) that references `querySelector`:

```
const qs = selector => document.querySelector(selector);
```

Then, whenever you need to select an element, use

```
qs('.demo')
```

(`qs` is so short that there shouldn't be any need for autocomplete with tab and enter)

Comment: looks great like jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with a snippet (in one of your snippets files):

```
"doc.qs": {
  "prefix": "dq",
  "body": [

    "const ${1/[.#](.*)/$1/} = document.querySelector('$1')",
    "$0"

  ],
  "description": "doc.querySelector expander"
},
```

[image: doc.querySelector snippet expander demo]

Just `dq` (or whatever prefix you want), <kbd>Tab</kbd>, enter your selector and <kbd>Tab</kbd> again.

Comment: tried not working, http://prntscr.com/qqnbiz is it wrong to put the code?

Comment: the `.` inside `[]` has no special meaning, you don't have to escape it: `[.#]` also works

Comment: @NIKHIL - it is a snippet, it doesn't go into your settings but into a snippet file. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets

Comment: great, I use it in the settings, lol. actually I was no idea but now working your code, thanks for help